# Simple Way to Check If Primitive is Uninitialized?

Tags: c, methods, conventions

In C, from what I understand, primitives like ints and floats are initialized to 0 when they are first declared. The same is true if a struct is declared that contains primitives. I'm having trouble finding a simple way to check if primitives are uninitialized or not.

For example, let's say I have an instance variable that is of type int declared in a header file. I need to use this variable in my implementation code, and it is important for me to know if this value has been initialized or not. Checking against zero isn't really an option, because if that value really is supposed to be zero then I've reinitialized a value that has already been changed. Checking against NULL also won't work, because it isn't a pointer.

The only solution that I've come up with is initializing the variable in the first piece of executable code to some value that I know will never be relevant to the rest of the program. For example, if the value should never be below zero, then I initialize it to -1 to know that it hasn't been initialized yet. This seems really crufty though, and can cause problems if the range of values to which the variable can be assigned changes.

Any interesting suggestions to this kind of problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using an uninitialized variable is an UB.
If you pass the switch -Wall (gcc) you can track every uninitialized variable. The gcc will reports something like this: `ddd.c:8: warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function`

Answer (score 7):

Your understanding is incorrect. Local variables are uninitialized regardless of being `int` or `float`.

Only `static` variables are initialized to zero. You should initialize everything before use. Even if you feel your implementation initializes the variable, you shouldn't rely on that. The standard doesn't guarantee anything. Using an uninitialized variable is an undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, but this doesn't answer my question. What exactly should I initialize my instance variable to if its value will not be assigned until some later procedure? How would I check if it is initialized or uninitialized in other procedures?

Comment: @Zanneth: You shouldn't check the variable itself at all.  You should always initialize your variables before use.  If you have to rely on some delayed initialization mechanism for some reason, you should keep a flag around (either in the same variable, with a value like -1, if it's outside the range of acceptable values, or with a separate boolean flag that keeps track of the initialization of the variable).

Answer (score 2):

Only global primitives, pointers and data structures are initialized with zero; local variables or `malloc()`'d memory is not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the zero that an object with static storage duration is initialised with and a zero that your code has explicitly set.  A zero is just a zero.

All you can do is explicitly initialise it with a non-zero non-valid number (in the `.c` file that defines it):

foo.h:

```
extern double foo;
```

foo.c:

```
double foo = NAN;
```

Or, alternatively, accompany it with a flag variable that indicates if it's been initialised:

foo.h:

```
extern double foo;
extern int foo_initialised;
```

foo.c:

```
double foo;
int foo_initialised;
```